# UIView animate usingSpringWithDamping

Tags: core-animation

i created a shaperLayer, and the layer's path is provided by a bezierPath. the code as follow:

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    let bezierPath1 = UIBezierPath()

    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor

    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 140.935, y: 50), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 87.340, y: 50))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 50), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 198.5, y: 50), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 50))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 50), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 250.57, y: 50), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 299.064, y: 50))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0))
    bezierPath.close()



    bezierPath1.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
    bezierPath1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 81.5))
    bezierPath1.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 140.935, y: 139.099), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 81.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 87.340, y: 81.5))
    bezierPath1.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 139.09), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 198.5, y: 203.90), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 139.09))
    bezierPath1.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 81.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 250.57, y: 139.09), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 299.064, y: 81.5))
    bezierPath1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0))
    bezierPath1.close()

    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath1.cgPath
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {

            shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        }) { (finish) in

        }
    }
```

but the animation is not my wanted. i expected effect is like this:
[good effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPJyd.gif)

the actual effect is like this :
[real effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpdLW.gif)

i don't know why. it did not have bounce effect. i thik i missing something important, and Is there anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to animate the path using Core Animation, not the UIView animation block you used. The other issue, is you can't do spring animations for CALayer path value.. so, you'll have to either use keyframe animation (approximate the bounce with keyframes), or accept a normal easing type.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    let bezierPath1 = UIBezierPath()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor

        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 140.935, y: 50), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 87.340, y: 50))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 50), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 198.5, y: 50), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 50))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 50), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 250.57, y: 50), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 299.064, y: 50))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0))
        bezierPath.close()

        bezierPath1.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        bezierPath1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 81.5))
        bezierPath1.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 140.935, y: 139.099), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 81.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 87.340, y: 81.5))
        bezierPath1.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 139.09), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 198.5, y: 203.90), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 250.578, y: 139.09))
        bezierPath1.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 81.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 250.57, y: 139.09), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 299.064, y: 81.5))
        bezierPath1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0))
        bezierPath1.close()

        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath1.cgPath
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        animateThing()
    }

    func animateThing() {
        guard shapeLayer.animation(forKey: "path") == nil else {
            return
        }
        let myAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        myAnimation.duration = 0.5
        myAnimation.fromValue = bezierPath1.cgPath
        myAnimation.toValue = bezierPath.cgPath
        myAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        myAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth

        shapeLayer.add(myAnimation, forKey: "path")
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    }
}
```